# Как создать форму в С++?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, c++

Зная VBA, прочитал книгу по языку С++. Узнал на Хешкоде, в какой среде лучше всего писать программы. Выбрал MS visual Studio. И вот открываю, создаю проект, а инструментов и формы не могу найти... Кочено мастером получается, но раньше было привычней на ВБА, когда там появляется уже готовое пустое окно-форма и слева инструменты... Подcкажите, как мне создать пустую форму? Спасибо.

Comment: Ковыряюсь еще. Конечно, и сам разберусь, но быстрее спросить. )

Comment: Вопрос не совсем в тему форума, справочные материалы по IDE нужно гуглить.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно при создании проекта Windows Form Application создаётся уже готовое окно с конструкторами и необходимым кодом для его компиляции и запуска. Если панель с кнопками и другим содержимым не появляется, то во View нужно выбрать Toolbox и тут вам будут базовые визуальные компоненты, которые вы можете помещать на форму. А если форма не появилась, то в Solution Explorer нажмите на Form1 правой кнопкой и далее на View Designer.